# Permission denied for <file://> to get property XPCComponents.utils in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to use `Reflect.parse` in my JavaScript in Firefox.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API) says to import this into the global object via

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/reflect.jsm")
```

However, this results in the following error message:

```
Error: Permission denied for <file://> to get property XPCComponents.utils
```

I have tried this in Firefox 11 and Aurora.

How can I get access to `Reflect.parse`?

**EDIT:**

The error message is due to the following fragment:

```
Component.utils
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real solution to this problem. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API) on `Reflect.parse` in the wiki is misleading, to say the least.

If you want a "pure" JavaScript solution in SpiderMonkey/Firefox, don't rely on `Reflect.parse`.

I see a lot of projects using the parser from [Narcissus](https://github.com/mozilla/narcissus) and I should have done the same.

**EDIT:** The [Esprima project](http://code.google.com/p/esprima/) is an excellent implementation of the Mozilla Parser API. After replacing `Reflect.parse` with `esprima.parse` all my 150+ test cases were still green, except for 5 or so dealing with non-standard SpiderMonkey extensions like `let` expressions (which I find pretty impressive).

Comment: Can you elaborate on examples where let is not supported? It works just fine, try it yourself with the online demo: http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html.

Comment: `let (x=3) x*x`: unexpected token '('

Comment: AFAIC that's a LetStatement and not a LexicalDeclaration. I don't think the former has made it into ES6 draft specification yet, so it still remains a SpiderMonkey extension so far.

Comment: Yes, LetExpressions and LetStatements are not (yet?) supported by Esprima, but you are quite right that they are non-standard. I will edit my answer to avoid any confusion. (In my case, I need the `let`s in the AST because I'm performing program transformations and want the possibility of introducing new variables on-the-fly without messing up the scope.)

Comment: `let` (and `const`) in a variable declaration is supported just fine, though. Example: `let x = 42; const y = 0`. This can be combined with a block scope to emulate a let statement.

Comment: Indeed. I prototyped my program transformations in Scheme, so that would explain my fixation on let-expressions. But a BlockStatement with a let declaration will have to do for now. Thanks.